# JQuery iterate over table rows

Tags: jquery, html

I have not used JQuery in a while and was trying to do something simple. Knowing the table id, iterate over each table row and get the id of each table row.
I tried the following but it isn't working

```
$("#tableId tr" ).each(function(){
      var $row = $(this);
      var rowId= $row.attr('id');
      console.log("rowId = ", rowId);
});
```

Nothing is getting printed on the console. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Mind sharing your HTML? [I don't seem to see a problem with that code.](http://jsfiddle.net/4tgc372e/3/)

Comment: Are you sure that each row has an id?

Comment: ^ That's probably the case. I doubt every row has an id. I don't see anything wrong with your code.

Comment: Can you post an HTML section example to be processed by this jQuery code? My only suggestion now is to make sure that the "tableId" ID string is consistent with the ID value defined in the HTML.

Comment: It's working for you?? http://fiddle.jshell.net/nMhmS/1449/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me:
$("#tableId tr").each((a,b)=> console.log("rowId = ", b.id));

edit:  Your answer is equivalent and should actually work?  I've had problems with Jquery and malformed html in the past.  Run your html through a validator maybe and see if that's an issue?

Also just for completeness sake if anyone.e ads that -- that's es6 syntax, so obviously doesn't work if the browser doesn't support it.  Can do same thing with function declaration.

Comment: Thank you- looks like there was some incorrect HTML